# How does serialization of lazy fields work?

Tags: scala, serialization

I know the benefits of lazy fields when a postponed evaluation of values is needed for some reasons. I was wondering what was the behavior of lazy fields in terms of serialization.

Consider the following class.

```
class MyClass {
  lazy val myLazyVal = {...}
  ...
}
```

**Questions:**

- If an instance of *MyClass* is serialized, does the lazy field get serialized too ?
- Does the behavior of serialization change if the field has been accessed or not before the serialization ? I mean, if I don't cause the evaluation of the field, is it considered as *null* ?
- Does the serialization mechanism provoke an implicit evaluation of the lazy field ?
- Is there a simple way to avoid the serialization of the variable and getting the value recomputed one more time lazily after the deserialization ? This should happen independently from the evaluation of the field.

Comment: what do you mean by "serialization"? I hope you're not using standard java serialization in scala. Which serialization library are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Answers**

1. Yes if field was already initialized, if not you can tread it as a method. Value is not computed -> not serialized, but available after de serialization.
2. If you didn't touch field it's serialized almost as it's a simple 'def' method, you don't need it's type to be serializable itself, it will be recalculated after de-serialization
3. No
4. You can add @transient before lazy val definition in my code example, as I understand it will do exactly what you want

**Code to prove**

```
object LazySerializationTest extends App {

  def serialize(obj: Any): Array[Byte] = {
    val bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val out = new ObjectOutputStream(bytes)
    out.writeObject(obj)
    out.close()
    bytes.toByteArray
  }

  def deSerialise(bytes: Array[Byte]): MyClass = {
    new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)).
      readObject().asInstanceOf[MyClass]
  }

  def test(obj: MyClass): Unit = {
    val bytes = serialize(obj)
    val fromBytes = deSerialise(bytes)

    println(s"Original cnt = ${obj.x.cnt}")
    println(s"De Serialized cnt = ${fromBytes.x.cnt}")
  }

  object X {
    val cnt = new AtomicInteger()
  }

  class X {
    // Not Serializable
    val cnt = X.cnt.incrementAndGet
    println(s"Create instance of X #$cnt")
  }

  class MyClass extends Serializable {
    lazy val x = new X
  }

  // Not initialized
  val mc1 = new MyClass
  test(mc1)

  // Force lazy evaluation
  val mc2 = new MyClass
  mc2.x
  test(mc2) // Failed with NotSerializableException

}
```

Comment: Attention: Marking the lazy field as `@transient` will (probably) not mark the bit masks the lazy val uses internally as `@transient`. Therefore, they will be serialized. You will end up with a badly initialized/unitialized lazy val when deserializing.

Comment: I tried adding transient to the code above and looks like it's totally ok. I would say if mask is not marked as transient it's scalac bug

Comment: Well, its a bug in either case then. The mask may be shared between multiple lazy vals. If one of them is `@transient` and the other not, what do you do? (Yes, the correct behavior would be to not share them then. Unfortunately I have my doubts about that).

Comment: Tx EugeneZhulenev and gzm0, very informative. BTW, how do I know in which version of scala this commit has been included?

Comment: I think I found, right after the commit message I can click to get the list of release tags.